# How to pass a derived class to a function accepting the parent type

Tags: java, android

I have a Sport base class that has a couple variables. I also have a few different classes derived from Sport such as Volleyball, Soccer, etc. that have additional methods and variables. They look somewhat like this.

```
public class Sport {
    public String commonVar;
    public Sport(String c) {
        this.commonVar = c;
    }
}
```

And then Volleyball:

```
public class Volleyball extends Sport {
    public String onlyVolleyball;
    public Volleyball(String c, String thisVar) {
        super(c);
        this.onlyVolleyball = thisVar;
    }
}
```

Now I want to be passing the derived classes of Sport into a function elsewhere, but making the parameters

```
public otherFunction(int one, int two, Sport sport) { }
```

Only treats sport as a Sport object (it will accept the derived classes but I cannot access any of the variables and methods not common to Sport). My question is how do I create a function that I am able to send all types of Sport derivatives to without losing any data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, but you can check if the object is actually a member of the extending class, then cast it and use it, as follows:

```
public otherFunction(int one, int two, Sport sport)
{
    if(sport instanceof Volleyball)
    {
        Volleyball volley = (Volleyball) sport;
        //Do Volleyball things
    }
    else
    {
        //Only do sport things.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm probably looking for, is there a way to do the casting more automatically? I can set a variable in Sport like
`public Class<? extends Sport> c;`
And set c from the derived class in the constructor.

Comment: @Ahorner Not really, you can't dynamically cast except in classes which have an extended type parameter (e.g. `ArrayList<String>`) because the generic declaration ensures type safety.  If you take a look at the source code for it, you'll see `E` is used to mean the extending type, and in the `elementData()` method, the value is cast as `(E) elementData[index]`, however that would only apply in this case if they shared all their methods with each other. (ArrayList soruce: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't. If that function is to work with the abstraction Sport then all the information it needs should be available in Sport. Else you should really have functions (or strategies/handlers or similar) for each.

You are breaking the Open Closed Principle (the O in SOLID) in object orientation principles.

You CAN do it though, with `instanceof` checks and then cast:

```
if (sport instanceof Volleyball) {
  Volleyball v = (Volleyball)sport;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, solution to your problem depends on what do you really want to achieve.

At the same time, considering your post, in my opinion you are attempting to mix different responsibilities, which are:

1. Handling Sport instances.
2. Handling derivatives of Sport instances.

Possibly this means that your method does not require Sport instances at all. 
What does it actually need is access to specific sports. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Therefore most simple solution would be to declare otherFunction like following:

```
public otherFunction(int one, int two, VolleyBall sport)
public otherFunction(int one, int two, Soccer sport)
public otherFunction(int one, int two, BasketBall sport)
public otherFunction(int one, int two, AnyOtherAwsomeSport sport)
```

In this way you are clearly telling what kind of sports your function is handling
and moreover you have quite clear interface that is easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: You are correct in this assumption. I think `instanceof` would probably be a smaller code footprint in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you cannot.  You'll need to add members, possibly abstract methods, like getTypeOfSport(), for example, to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with the "expression problem"; it is hard to solve. One thing you can do is this:

```
public interface SportFunction {
    void doChessFunction(Chess sport);
    void doVolleyballFunction(Volleyball sport);
}

public abstract class Sport {
    public String commonVar;
    public Sport(String c) {
        this.commonVar = c;
    }
    public abstract void doSportFunction(SportFunction function);
}

public class Volleyball extends Sport {
    public String onlyVolleyball;
    public Volleyball(String c, String thisVar) {
        super(c);
        this.onlyVolleyball = thisVar;
    }

    public void doSportFunction(SportFunction function) {
        function.doVolleyballFunction(this);
    }
}

public class Chess extends Sport {
    public int onlyChess;
    public Chess(String c, int thisVar) {
        super(c);
        this.onlyChess = thisVar;
    }

    public void doSportFunction(SportFunction function) {
        function.doChessFunction(this);
    }
}
```

And then use the classes like this:

```
public void otherFunction(int one, int two, Sport sport) {
   sport.doSportFunction(new OtherSportFunction(one, two));
}

public class OtherSportFunction implements SportFunction {
   public OtherSportFunction(int one, int two) { /* do stuff */ }
   public void doChessFunction(Chess sport) { /* do chess stuff */ }
   public void doVolleyballFunction(Volleyball sport) { /* do volleyball stuff */ }
}
```